# Is it possible to create a tutorial world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have just bought Minecraft (Better Together version) for my Xbox One. My friend has Minecraft: Xbox One Edition, and he can create tutorial worlds, which are fun to blow up.

So, is it possible to create a tutorial world with Minecraft (Better Together)?

Comment: Well... If your friend can do it, I suppose it's possible, right?

Comment: Do you mean he built something in the world that could be used as a tutorial or do you mean that there actually is a tutorial built into Minecraft console? Also: Why do you need a tutorial for Minecraft? Just move around and try doing different things. And if you want to blow something up, just make any new world and blow that  one up. I recommend a repeating command block with `execute @r[type=!player] ~ ~ ~ summon tnt` btw. I just read that it's not possible to download worlds on Minecraft console (for whatever reason), so that's also not a possibility for you.

Comment: No, there is a pre-built tutorial world, meant to teach you Minecraft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Microsoft official Minecraft Windows 10 Edition (included in the Better Together Update), at http://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-titles/minecraft-windows-10-edition-faq :

[image]

It looks like there is no tutorial world in the Better Together update. You could maybe check out [this link](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:17111) for the Pocket Edition, but it doesn't look like it's a legitimate tutorial world, and I don't see a download. It looks like no tutorial world. Sorry!